# ArrayList doesnt return elements when changing fragments after get request from api

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a method that call a api and fill a ArrayList with data. The method is in a fragment, when I open the App it adds data to the arrayList, but when I go to another fragment or activity and come back it doesnt show any in the recyclerview from the ArrayList as if nothing is there, but when I toast the size of array, it returns the number of elements that should be there
but it doesnt show/populate the recyclerview with the elements.
I call the method in onCreateView()

CALLING API
private void getDataFromUAPI(String gist_json_url){

```
    requestQueue = MySingleton.getInstance(this.getContext()).getRequestQueue();
    request = new JsonArrayRequest(Method.GET, gist_json_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i ++){
                try {

                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    User user = new User();

                    // if this user Id is not user Id of the user and
                    // if user are already been followed, than don't add
                    if (!jsonObject.getString("id").equals(firebaseUser.getUid()) && !sharedPreferences.contains(jsonObject.getString("id"))) {
                        user.setPhoto(jsonObject.getString("photo"));
                        user.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                        user.setFnumber(jsonObject.getString("fnumber"));
                        user.setId(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                        responseList.add(user);
                    }

                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), user.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(responseList.size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ERROR \n" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(request);
```